# Using fgets and strtok to read a file in C?

Tags: c, pointers, fgets, strtok

I am currently writing a small program for school and we have to use fgets and strtok to read the file.

```
input.txt is:
Redden 2 0
Berglund 5 2
Jackman 2 0
Stewart 4 0
Oshie 3 5
McDonald 2 4
```

Here is the relevant code

```
int main(int arg, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1]);
    char **names=NULL;
    int *goals=NULL;
    int *assists=NULL;
    int size = countLinesInFile(fp);
    allocateMemory(&goals, &assists, &names, size);
    readLines(fp, goals, assists, names, size);
}

void allocateMemory(int** goals, int** assists, char*** names, int size) {
    *goals = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    *assists = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    *names = malloc(size*sizeof(char *));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
       *(*names + i) = malloc(MAX_NAME*sizeof(char));
    }
}

void readLines(FILE *ptr, int *goals, int *assists, char **names, int size) {
    char *line=malloc(MAX_LINE*sizeof(char));
    int i;
    char *token=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if(fgets(line,MAX_LINE, ptr)!=NULL); {
            token=strtok(line,"");//segfaulting somewhere around these lines
            strcpy(names[i],token);
            token=strtok(NULL,"\n");
            goals[i]=atoi(token);
            token=strtok(NULL,"\n");
            assists[i]=atoi(token);
        }
    }
    free(line);
}
```

So I am segfaulting and it's telling me it's occurring in the readLines function and have no idea how to fix this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You aren't checking *any* of the return values of the functions you call for success. For example, the very first line of `readLines` calls `malloc`, but you have no way of knowing whether that allocation succeeded. You just go on using `*line` assuming that it is valid when it might not be. You also should try stepping through your code with a debugger to see exactly *why* the segfault is occurring.

Comment: In `token=strtok(line,"");` you want to break the line on an empty string (you forgot the space).

Answer (score 2):

One problem is the calls to `strtok`. Your file uses space as delimiter, so you should do the same:

```
    if(fgets(line,MAX_LINE, ptr)!=NULL); {
        token=strtok(line," ");
        strcpy(names[i],token);
        token=strtok(NULL," ");
        goals[i]=atoi(token);
        token=strtok(NULL," ");
        assists[i]=atoi(token);
    }
```

Note that the third token will contain a `\n` character. The `\n` is ignored by `atoi`. If you want it stripped from the returned token, substitute `" \n"` for the last argument to `strtok`.